# How are short and long form adjectives used differently?

Tags: грамматика, прилагательные

I'm confused by long form adjectives (which seem to be more common) and short form adjectives. For example, from **свобода** (freedom) there is the long form adjective **свободный** and the short form adjective **свободен**. How are these forms used differently? Why do two different forms exist (in general)?

Comment: this is interesting read: http://blogs.transparent.com/russian/how-to-use-russian-adjectival-short-form/

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Short adjectives are often used as predicates. I can say `Он закончил работу, поэтому он свободен`. I can convey the same message by using the long adjective: `Он закончил работу, поэтому он свободный`, though the first version is more common.

However, you can't use short adjectives as attributes. For example, I can say `Свободный человек может заниматься всем, чем захочет`, but I can't replace the first word with `свободен`, because it is an attribute.

Comment: I'd say, in modern Russian, a short form adjective is *nearly always* used as a predicate. When it is not, it is certainly part of an idiomatic expression (examples: *красна девица*, *от мала до велика* and others).

Comment: _Sometimes_ short form _hints_ at the fact that the attribute is temporary, or is presented not fully, or it only describes the subject partially, and the subject has many other important attributes. `Я свободен` may mean "I don't have any work now", but `Я свободный` implies permanent quality. `Птица Говорун  умна и сообразительна` sounds more natural then `умная и сообразительная`, as we name two attributes.

Answer (score 6):

свободный - is more of a quality like 'a free spot'

свободен - is more of a state,  how you feel, like 'i am free to do things'

the difference is subtle and depends on the exact meaning

Answer (score 6):

In Proto-Slavic, third-person pronouns were used as grammatical articles to form pronominal adjectives:

- великъ домъ (a large house) / великъ-jь домъ (this house is large)
- глубока рѣка (a deep river) / глубока-ja рѣка (this river is deep)

**jь* and **ja* here are extinct third-person pronouns meaning a local person participating in the conversation (as opposed to a remote person designated with *он, она*).

Their traces remain in the language in oblique cases (*его* but not *оного*, *ему* but not *оному* etc.)

Comment: Doesn't really answer the question, but this was a very interesting piece of information. +1

Comment: Exactly, not великъ-iй, but великъ + jь -> великы˅jь.

Answer (score 4):

`Свободный` is a persistent attribute, `свободен` is a temporary attribute. But often the meaning is just the same.

Read [this article "Краткая форма прилагательных" on the Russian Wikipedia](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85) to find out more, there are a number of different cases.

Answer (score 3):

- Свобода - freedom
- Свободен - free to do something. (Also used to indicate you are free to go") When a prisoner is released from jail he would say "я свободен" or "я на свободе"
- Свободный - is, like you said an adjective describing the state of things. He is a free man, он свободный человек

Comment: What about other adjectives, such as молодой/молод or широкий/широк... Would it be "(too) young to do something" and "(too) wide to do something" respectively?

Comment: `молодой` - answers to "he is ..", `молод` - answers to "he is a kind of"

Answer (score 2):

свободен I would use when "is" in english translation. "He is free = Он свободен"

свободный I would use with the following noun in the sentence. "Free chair may be occupied - Свободный стул может быть занят"

Answer (score 1):

Simple explanation:

Объект `свободен` в `свободном` месте.
An object is `free` at `inoccupied` place.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the short forms have a different meaning than the full forms. Here are some examples (I don't know the general rule):

*хороший* - *хорош* - *хорош собой*
*good*, *kind* - *tasty* (in some contexts) - *beautiful*

> Он хороший друг - He is a good friend.
>   Он хорош собой - He is handsome. It is incorrect to say "Он хороший собой."
>   Суп хорош! - The soup tastes good! It is weird (at least for me) to say "Суп хороший"

*сильный* - *силён* (в чем-либо) 
*strong* - *knowledgeable*

> Сильный мужчина - A strong man
>   Он силен в математике - He knows his maths.

*добрый* - *будь добр*
*kind* - *please*

> Добрый доктор Айболит - A good kind Dr. Айболит.
>   Будь добр, закрой окно. - Be a dear, close the window.

*великий* - *велик*
*great* - *too large*

> Пётр Великий - Peter The Great
>   Этот костюм мне велик - This suit is too large for me.

*смешной* - *смешон*
*funny* - *laughable, ridiculous*

> Смешная история - A funny story
>   Ты смешон - You are ridiculous.